# Kimono Desktop rss and autorun

Tags: kimono

I dont See that anyone already asked for this so

> 1.: Is there any way to Autorun like in online Kimono the tasks
>
> 2.: Did anyone get link to rss running?

It seams to runs on

http://localhost:3000

but when i Access it on ie,  ff ore chrome i just get a blank page...

But on looking into source of this page it show everything

So it seams to get hidden, in any way :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you actually can you access it at http://localhost:3000, but you need the complete API url as you would use from Kimono's web app.

Typically this will be:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/rss/<APINAME>?apikey=VoN0G0ULsa7rM7qqxVp2a66maHuv3Jkk
```

Where `<APINAME>` should be replaced with the value from the desktop app.

Also note that the value of "apikey" above is the same one you should use since it's coded into the desktop app for the desktop user.

Finally, if you use the "modify results" script, you need to add the following parameter to the end of your request:

```
&kimmodify=1
```

EDIT: The above URL just returns your last manual crawl results. The simplest way to actually trigger a new crawl/update in an automated fashion is to make a request to:

```
http://localhost:3000/ws/startcrawl?apiid=<APINAME>
```

Then give that crawl some time to complete and fetch the results from the first URL above.

Comment: Ahh, thx, this is nice, ondemand is perfect, i need this for always up2date rss

Comment: So I wasn't clear but this looks like http://localhost:3000/api/rss/ondemand/<API_ID>?apikey=VoN0G0ULsa7rM7qqxVp2a66maHuv3Jkk&kimmodify=1

Comment: So is this actually re-running the crawl - it does not appear so?

Comment: I original posted as a guest account, so my edit with corrected information didn't go through (when I realized it wasn't actually re-crawling). It's updated now.