# Kimono Desktop crawl stuck at "Queued"

Tags: kimono

I'm using Kimono Desktop to crawl a site and posting the data to a Firebase endpoint. Everything is working from beginning to end with the exception of auto-running.

When creating or editing the Kimono API with the Chrome extension the desktop app crawls and reports "the last crawl was successful". The next run is listed as the set time to crawl (I've tried 5 min, 30 min, and 1 hour on multiple machines) but when that time elapses the Next Auto-Run says "Queued" but never actually runs.

[Kimono Desktop Crawl Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6GKm.png)

The API in the screen shot above is set to crawl every five minutes but has been queued for at least 2 hours 55 minutes without running. And out of curiosity I let one machine go 2 days without another crawl.

Clicking Start Crawl works fine but defeats the purpose of the auto-run. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware the Kimono Desktop version does not support autorun.

There have been a few people who have found success by calling the api via ondemand with a script at their own determined intervals, which seems to be the only current way to do this now.

I'm sure more people will find ways to tinker with the desktop version as time goes on, but no luck with autorun so far for me unfortunately.

To find info on how to use the ondemand calls for the desktop version, some info on this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35742269/6037173) should be able to get you going.