# How to auto-run crawl on Kimono

Tags: web-crawler, kimono

I'm using Kimonolabs but I had [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189785/kimono-desktop-crawl-stuck-at-queued) with the auto crawl.

I have seen that **Xytrix** answered there is [a way to start the crawl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35742269/6240458), but I think that is the same thing if I do it from start's button ...

There is a way to do it automatically? I did this basic-caveman example using an existing API, and I want to refresh results automatically... How it's possible?

```
`http://codepen.io/Davi91/pen/ONwmoE`
```