# Passing URL to Kimono Desktop

Tags: kimono

I use KimonoDesktop to do some crawl. Very usefull and ergonomic.

But I need to use kimono with my program wrote in NodeJS. I was thinking about call an existing API by using an url. Something like that is explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707263/kimono-desktop-rss-and-autorun).

However I need to change the source URL (used to create the API). I need to change it **in my program**. That is my problem.

The official documentation ([here](https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203043684-Pass-through-new-URL-parameters-to-your-API)) explain how to do that... But I is only for the previous online API service. Now it seems that it does not work anymore.

Is that someone has already succeeded to call an API from kimono desktop by passing arguments to change the URL used to crawl ?

Thank you :)

Comment: When I try something like `http://localhost:3000/api/json/ondemand/`, I have : `{"error":"Unauthorized"}`. So I think that it must be possible to call that URL. I just need the right args, don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `apikey` query parameter with a proper API Key value.

The generous creators of this glorious app have provided a special "superuser" for the desktop app. This user's name is `Desktop User`. It has access to everything as far as I can tell.

As of April 30th, 2016 you can find that user's API key by searching for the word `apikey` in the `.../app/lib/create-user.js` file. On an Mac OS X computer, this file would be installed at `/Applications/Kimono.app/Contents/Resources/app/lib/create-user.js`. (This assumes you downloaded the Kimono Desktop app and dragged it into your Applications folder).

I'm pretty sure your `Desktop User`'s API key is the same as mine.  Feel free to leave the API key as a comment here for others. I'm just not sure whether the creators want the API key published publicly, whether it is the same for you as for me, or for how long it will work in case a patch is pushed out to the application.

---

Once you have your API key, you can start querying your APIs by doing something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/bz1m76?apikey=VoN0...3Jkk
```

Make sure that your Kimono Desktop is running. You can also check `/Applications/Kimono.app/Contents/Resources/app/config.json` to verify the first part of the url.